# How faster the map than JSON string in the hive data type?

Tags: json, dictionary, hadoop, hive, hiveql

there.

I'm considering data type in hive column, between json formatted string and map.

In my common sense, there are no arguments that the map type is definitely faster than `json string`. However, I have no idea how hive treats data in the map type, so I can't prove it.

If I just want to put some `single depth nested data` into a column, map is the best choice? and how faster than `json string`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map is also serialized as string and stored in strings. Data transferred between mapper and reducer is serialized in strings then de-serialized again. You will not notice the difference. But in case of map datatype SerDe will deserialize as Map type and you can directly apply map operators in the query like `select m[key]` or `size(m)` or `map_keys(m)`. **This looks much simpler than using `JSON_TUPLE()`** probably along with `lateral view` or `GET_JSON_OBJECT()`, in this case map may work a bit faster, though JSON can store more complex structures like nested arrays of maps.  Choose map if it suits your data and JSON for complex structures.